# How to open a spreadsheet in a specific folder using pygsheets

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

I'm using pygsheets to read data from a shared Google doc.
To open a spreadsheet I call

```
gc.open(sheet_name)
```

and this works. However, I would like to be able to use it by referring to the spreadsheet by its full path:

```
gc.open('Public spreadsheets/' + sheet_name)
```

I can't figure out how to do it (and whether it's even possible) with pygsheets.

Since this is the backend of a public facing app, I don't want the user to be able to access spreadsheets outside of that folder. (I guess I'll have to sanitise `sheet_name` as well, to make sure it's not something like `"../../Personal Stuff"`)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like an external library. You'd have to check if their [Docs pygsheets](http://pygsheets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) if this feature is supported which I don't think is.

It's clearly mentioned in their page:

> Open, create, delete and share spreadsheets using title or key (ONLY)

If you look at [Files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get) and [spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get), you'll notice that only spreadsheetId is required. You can always try to write your own library if the available APIs doesn't meet your specifications.